# Where to delete the dynamic memory "char p"?

Tags: c++

This is a hangman game program. I am declaring a char*p in the **main** which I can't understand why I am unable to delete later in the program when I don't need it. I tried it deleting later but it gives a heap memory error.
Also, I am a newbie in c++ - actually in programming - I will also appreciate if you can help me on how can I make the output of this program(on console) look more attractive and interactive. Like where should I use system("cls") commands more that can make it look more readable and remove non-essential information. Make a file in the same directory of the program with name either easy,medium or hard. so that it can have input from it when u run the program..

```
#pragma once    
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>  
#include<fstream>
#include<ctime>
#include <chrono> // for measuring time
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

//scoring the game with recard to time....
// filing : user name unique id and all that
//storing the name of user , his score, long story short, make a record of every user who passes by
int len = 0, letterCount = 0, size = 0, guesses = 6;

class tstamp
{
    time_point<system_clock>tstart;
    time_point<system_clock>tstop;
public:
    void start()
    {
        tstart = system_clock::now();
    }
    void stop()
    {
        tstop = system_clock::now();
    }
    long long elasped()
    {
        return duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(tstop - tstart).count();
    }
};

int checkWin(string a, char *p)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char *an = new char[a.length()];


    string word = p;

    for (i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == word[i])
            count++;

    }
    if (count == i)
        return 1; // 1 means the array is equal to the string  == win
    else
        return 0;  // not win
    delete[]an; // using delete here for 1st
}
void resetData(string nameOfPlayer)
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(nameOfPlayer + ".txt", ios::trunc);
    //fout << "No Record";
    fout.close();


}



void playerDetails(string nameOfPlayer, string a, bool status, float timeTaken)
{
    char check = '\0';


    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(nameOfPlayer + ".txt", ios::app);
    if (status == true)
        fout << "Status : WON" << endl;
    else
        fout << "Status : LOST" << endl;
    fout << "Word : " << a << endl;
    fout << "Time taken to guess : " << timeTaken << " seconds" << endl;
    fout << "********************************************";
    fout << endl << endl;
    fout.close();
}

string * grow(string *p, string temp)  // to regrow the string array!!!!!
{
    string* newArray = new string[size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i<size - 1; i++)
    {
        *(newArray + i) = *(p + i);

    }

    newArray[size - 1] = temp;
    delete[] p;
    return newArray;
}

char inGameMenu(char reset)
{
    reset = '\0';
    cout << "\n\t--->To reset your record press 'r' : ";
    cout << "\n\n\t--->To display your previous record press 'd' :  ";
    cout << "\n\n\t--->To continue press 'x' : ";
    cout << "\n\n\t--->To Exit the game press 'q' : ";
    cout << endl << "\n\n\t--->Your Choice : ";
    cin >> reset;
    return reset;


}

string provideWord(string *contents, string a)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = rand() % size;
    a = contents[i];
    return a;
}

string* read(string fileName, string contents[])
{
    string ext = ".txt";
    fileName = fileName + ext;
    fstream fin;
    fin.open(fileName);
    if (fin.is_open())
    {

        fin >> contents[0];
        size++;
        string temp;
        while (fin >> temp)
        {
            size++;
            contents = grow(contents, temp);
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "\n\tFile Not Found\n\n\n";
    return contents;
}

char * makeAsterisks(string temp)   // this will make astericks of the word player have to guess.
{
    int len = temp.length();
    char*p = new char[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        p[i] = '-';
    }
    p[len] = '\0';
    return p;
}

void displayRecord(string fileName, string display)
{
    fstream fout;
    fout.open(fileName + ".txt");
    cout << "\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    if (fout.is_open())
    {
        cout << endl << endl;
        while (getline(fout, display))
            cout << display << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "\n!!No Record Found!!\nYou might be a new user\n";
    cout << "\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    fout.close();
}


char * checkMyGuess(string word, char userGuess, char ar[])
{
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if (userGuess == word[i])
        {
            flag = false;
            ar[i] = userGuess;
            letterCount++;
        }
    }
    if (flag == true)
    {
        _beep(450, 100);
        cout << "\n\t!!!Wrong!!!\n";
        len--;
        guesses--;
    }
    return ar;
}
void rules()
{
    system("Color 09 "); // for color effects

    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t=====================\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t||\tHANGMAN\t    ||\n\t\t\t||\tRules\t    ||"
        << "\n " << "\t\t\t=====================\n\n\n";
    _beep(4000, 500);

    system("Color 08 ");  // for color effects
    system("Color 07 "); // for color effects

    cout << "\t--> Computer will think of a word and you have try\n"   // rules
        << "\t to guess what it is one letter at a\n"
        << "\t time. Computer will draw a number of dashes \n "
        << "\tequivalent to the number of letters in the word.\n "
        << "\t If you suggest a letter that occurs\n "
        << "\t in the word, the computer will fill in the blank(s)\n"
        << "\t with that letter in the right place(s).\n"
        << "\t The session will be timed. \n\n";

    cout << endl;
    cout << "\t--> Total number of wrong choices : 6\n\n";  //wrong turns
    cout << "\t--> Objective : Guess the word / phrase before you run out of choices!\n\n";   // obj



}
int checkForName(string fileName)
{
    fileName = fileName + ".txt";
    char line = '\0';
    fstream fin;
    char fromFile[7] = "\t\tName";
    fin.open(fileName);

    int i = 0,
        check = 0;
    while (fin.get(line) && i < 7)
    {
        if (line == fromFile[i++])
            check++;
    }
    if (check == i - 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    fin.close();

}
void checkForRecord(string fileName)
{
    fileName = fileName + ".txt";
    char line = '\0';
    fstream fin;
    char fromFile[7] = "No";
    fin.open(fileName);

    int i = 0,
        check = 0;
    while (fin.get(line) && i < 3)
    {
        if (line == fromFile[i++])
            check++;
    }
    if (check == i - 1)
    {
        fin.open(fileName, ios::trunc);
        fin.close();
    }

    fin.close();

}
int menu(int mode) // this function asks the user to enter the difficulty level of the game!!! You can't even beat medium!
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Please select the Level of Game :\n";
    cout << "1. Easy" << endl;
    cout << "2. Medium" << endl;
    cout << "3. Hard" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Your Choice : ";
    cin >> mode;
    while (!(mode <= 3 && mode >= 1))
    {
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "Please Enter the number of given choices: ";
        cin >> mode;

    }
    return mode;
}
int comMenu(string nameOfPlayer, char reset)
{
    string readData;
    reset = '\0';
    while (1)
    {

        reset = inGameMenu(reset);
        if (reset == 'r')
        {
            resetData(nameOfPlayer);

            system("cls");
            Sleep(1);
        }
        else if (reset == 'd')
        {
            system("cls");
            Sleep(1);  // just to add a little delay!
            cout << "Your Record Shows :--->\n";
            displayRecord(nameOfPlayer, readData);
        }
        else if (reset == 'x')
            break;
        else if (reset == 'q')
            break;
        else
        {
            cout << "\n\n!!!Invalid Choice!!!\n\n";
        }
    }
    return reset;
}


int main()
{

    string nameOfPlayer;
    char anyKey = '\0';
    string name;
    cout << endl;

    rules();

    cout << "Enter the name of player: ";
    cin >> nameOfPlayer;



    while (1)
    {

        char reset = '\0';
        reset = comMenu(nameOfPlayer, reset);

        if (reset != 'q')  // check to exit the game
        {

            int uniquevar = checkForName(nameOfPlayer);
            if (uniquevar != 1)
            {
                ofstream fout;
                fout.open(nameOfPlayer + ".txt", ios::app);
                fout << "\t\tName of Player : " << nameOfPlayer << endl << endl << endl;   
                fout.close();
            }
            while (1)
            {
                system("Color E0");
                bool status = true; //initially win
                size = 0,
                    len = 0,
                    letterCount = 0,
                    guesses = 6;
                string a = ""; // it holds the word
                string *contents = new string[1];
                string name = "";
                char b;
                int mode = 0;
                tstamp ts;
                bool notRepeat[26] = { 0 };
                if (anyKey == 'X' || anyKey == 'x')
                    break;
                else
                {
                    mode = menu(mode);
                    if (mode == 1)
                        name = "easy";
                    else if (mode == 2)
                        name = "medium";
                    else if (mode == 3)
                        name = "hard";

                    contents = read(name, contents);
                    cout << endl;

                }
                a = provideWord(contents, a);
                delete[]contents;

                len = a.length();
                char *p = makeAsterisks(a);  // detele it later
                cout << "Total number of words to guesses: " << len << endl << endl;
                cout << "Total guesses you have: 6\n";
                cout << "Word :\n\n\t" << p << endl << endl;
                ts.start(); // it starts counting the time...
                while (guesses != 0)
                {
                    cout << "Enter char: ";
                    cin >> b;
                    if (b >= '1' && b <= '9')
                    {
                        cout << "\n\nThere is not number in the given word\n\n";
                        continue;
                    }
                    int temp = b - 97; //  it assigns the value of alphabet to temp i.e a=0,b=0 so on...

                    if (notRepeat[temp] != false)
                    {
                        cout << "\n\nYou've already used this word\n\n";
                        cout << "Remaining Choices: " << guesses << endl << endl;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        p = checkMyGuess(a, b, p);
                        int checkingTheWin = checkWin(a, p);
                        if (checkingTheWin == 0)
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout << "\n\n\t*************You Won****************\n\n";
                            status = true; //true = win
                            break;
                        }
                        notRepeat[temp] = true;

                        cout << endl << endl;
                        cout << "Remaining Choices: " << guesses << endl;
                        cout << endl << '\t' << p << endl;
                    }
                }
                ts.stop();
                cout << "Time Taken: " << ts.elasped() << " seconds\n\n";
                p = NULL;
                if (guesses == 0)
                {
                    status = false; //false = lose
                    checkForRecord(nameOfPlayer);
                    playerDetails(nameOfPlayer, a, status, time); // right here it will create a file with the name of user
                    cout << "\n\nGame Over!!!\n\n";
                    cout << "\t\tThe word was \n\t\t\" " << a << "\"\n\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    checkForRecord(nameOfPlayer);
                    playerDetails(nameOfPlayer, a, status, time); // right here it will create a file with the name of user
                }
                
                break;

            }  //ending block of while(1) first
            system("color 07");  // shashka!!
        }

        if (reset == 'q') // to exit the game if the user decides so right away!!
            break;
    }
    
    cout << "Exiting the Game\n\n";
    _beep(3000, 500);  // ending sound!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember that `return` causes the function to exit *immediately*. Secondly, in the `checkWin` function, what do you intend to use `an` for? It's not used right now.

Comment: Oh and for strings you shouldn't really use pointers and dynamic allocation, use `std::string`. And for "dynamic arrays", use `std::vector`.

Comment: Lastly, please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget the *minimal* part of your [mcve].

Comment: Unrelated: Remove `#include <stdlib.h>`. You already include the correct one, `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: Within `makeAsterisks(string temp)` you access non allocated heap (`p[len]`). `p` ranges from `0` to `len - 1`.

Comment: Unrelated 2: `#pragma once` is a form of _header guard_. Don't use it in `.cpp` files. `.cpp` files should _very rarely_ be `#include`d.

Comment: I think you need `len + 1` here btw :   `char*p = new char[len];` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `makeAsterisks` you don't allow for the null terminator. You need to allocate one more character

```
char * makeAsterisks(string temp) 
{
    int len = temp.length();
    char*p = new char[len + 1]; // <-- change here
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        p[i] = '-';
    }
    p[len] = '\0';
    return p;
}
```

Now having said that, you are already using `string`, why not make life easier for yourself and use it everywhere? Here's `makeAsterisks` rewritten to use `string`.

```
string makeAsterisks(string temp) 
{
     return string(temp.length(), '-');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , Again the question remains that where should I delete the char*p if I have decided to use it?

Comment: Delete it after you no longer need it. The error you have before should no longer happen with the fix above.

Comment: Thanks bruh that worked.. Why it was showing error before?
why does it matter? I was just deleting what was being initialized and used and the same is what i am doing rn!

Comment: The error was that you didn't allocate enough memory and you accessed memory beyond what you had allocated. When you do that the behaviour of your program becomes unpredictable. This is an important fact about programming C++, the line where the program crashes is not (necessarily) the line with the error.